# MySQL Workbench cannot open on Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

MySQL Workbench on Mac (10.14) opens only for a moment and closes immediately without any (visible) error message. Re-installing it does not solve the problem.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: You have to split the question from an answer. And if you want to answer yourself, mark it correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the rather massive edit of the question, but you should formulate postings on SO in a Q&A style: a simple question/description about the problem and a simple answer for it (no decorations like: "Hi", "thanks", "I'm a beginner" and such).

Comment: Thank you for editing my post :D.

Answer (score 38):

MySQLWorkbench need Python3.7 Framework in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions

1. brew install python@3.7
2. sudo cp -r /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.7/3.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
3. open MySQLWorkbench, it's work

Comment: just wanted to point out that this worked for me and a number of my devs

Comment: Glad to hear that ;)

Comment: This actually was the only way to get MySQLWorkbench working again. Plz note MySQLWorkbench looks for this exactly version 3.7. Stupid, if you ask me. Anyway, good answer.

Comment: This works, for me too on Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: The only solution that worked for me. Indeed, it only worked with 3.7.* (failed for 3.9.*) as @medina mentioned above, and I agree: it's quite silly.

Comment: Instead of copying the folder, creating a symbolic link is my prefered way: sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.7/3.7.10_3/Frameworks/Python.framework /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
Anyway, thank you for your answer @yakob

Comment: Works for my Python 3.7 and Monterey.

Answer (score 9):

I solved downloading an older version of Workbench (8.0.20)

Comment: This is the quickest way to go about it (latest ver that manifests this problem is 8.0.23). No need to mess with Python and potentially mess up other things.

Answer (score 9):

One solution worked with me:

`System Preferences` -> `Security & Privacy` -> click “`Open Anyway`”.

And don't forget to unlock the Lock icon at the bottom left.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but it did not run even I pressed Open Anyway. Maybe my case was a special one.

Comment: I think you need to click on the lock at the bottom left before clicking 'Open Anyway'

Answer (score 3):

I faced this problem when my mac was updated to Monterey. I downloaded the workbench again from this link [Official Mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) and installed it. I replaced the older workbench into my Applications and was able to retrieve servers i setup with the older workbench.
Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

macOS Monterey, using version ( 8.0.29 ) solved the issue

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things potentially going on.

One is the Mac Security and Privacy control, addressed nicely by Mahmoud Mostafa in another answer.

But even once that's gotten around, there is the problem of where this app is looking for Python. Running Catalina 10.15.7, I used the terminal command suggested by Phil Nguyen and got a different error message:

> Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec, sys.path = ['/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/libraries', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload']
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

To my surprise, I saw that there was no `Python.framework` within `/Library/Frameworks/` at all. I'd been using Anaconda, which installed Python under my user directory.

As I had also installed Xcode tools, I just made a symbolic link* within `/Library/Frameworks/` pointing to the Python framework at

> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework

and changed the name of the symbolic link to `Python.framework`. That provides a Python 3.7 instead of forcing things back to Python 2 or using an old version of Workbench. Worked for me; YMMV.

---

*This needs to be a symbolic link made by `ln -s` in a Terminal window and not a Finder-generated alias. Working in `/Library/Frameworks/` will require `sudo`.

Comment: The full command to create a symbolic link suggested in this answer: `sudo ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as above. Downloading the older version from archives resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal and type:

```
/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/MySQLWorkbench --verbose
```

if your terminal said:

```
Your PYTHONPATH points to a site-packages dir for Python 3.x but you are running Python 2.x!
PYTHONPATH is currently: ":/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/libraries"
You should `unset PYTHONPATH` to fix this.
```

Type this:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Comment: Dear friends, my latest solution is throwing my Mac and buy a new windows laptop.

Comment: This step is very useful for figuring out you need to put python 3.7 in a place accessible to workbench. Would have no idea why the other solution worked if not for the verbose messages.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using macOS 10.15 or lesser version just switch to older version of workbench(8.0.11), which is the stabile version and compatible with macOS 10.15 or lesser version. For download [Click here](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/)

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded the OS and I faced the issue with the Workbench. It was not loading. So, I downloaded it and installed it again. I got an option to keep both or replace them. I choose to Replace. This resolved the loading issue. Now, it's opening.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command in your terminal, to remove the app from quarantine:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/MySQLWorkbench.app
```

Note that the default path is /Applications, i.e., the default filename is /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app

Answer (score 0):

I just installed newer version and it automatically replaced the old version and it worked!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/MySQLWorkbench --verbose

I opened with this command once and it after that it started opening normally.

PS I have python 3.7 installed

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced a similar problem after upgrading MAC OS To Monterey,
The solution worked just upgrade your MySQL Workbench 8.0.30.
Link: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/